# How to convert a string variable to a checkBox object Name in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the property of an existing `CheckBox` object in my code:

```
string checkBoxName = "checkBox" + Convert.ToString(index);    
Object objCheckBox = checkBoxName;    
CheckBox myCheckBox = objCheckBox as CheckBox;

if (words[1] == "-1")
{
    myCheckBox.Checked = false;
}
else
{
    myCheckBox.Checked = true;
}
```

The code snippet above did not cause a compile error but caused a runtime error as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What should I do?

Comment: You are saving a `string` in `objCheckBox` and trying to convert that as `CheckBox`. That obviously won't work.

Comment: @Nolonar If it was that obvious, the OP wouldn't have tried it that way, would he?

Comment: I agree, it was a stupid approach :D.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Of course he would have. Lack of experience/knowledge/focus. I usually do some really stupid and obvious mistakes myself, spend hours trying to resolve the problem, then curse myself for not noticing the obvious sooner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I'm assuming that you're talking about WinForms*

You can not do it that way. The following line assigns `null` to `myCheckBox`, as `objCheckBox` is of type `string` and not of type `CheckBox`.

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = objCheckBox as CheckBox;
```

What you need to do is iterate all controls on the form to find the control named `checkBoxName`. You can do it via LINQ, or you can do it like this:

```
Control[] controls = this.Find(checkBoxName, true);
if (controls != null && controls.Length > 0)
{
    (controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked = words[1] != "-1";
}
```

A LINQ approach could look like this:

```
Control c = (from Control c in this.Controls where c.Name.Equals(checkBoxName) select c).FirstOrDefault();
if (c != null)
{
    ....
}
```

Please note that if the `CheckBox` is not a direct child of the form itself, the LINQ approach won't find it. To make sure it is always found, you'll need to recursively also search container controls - for example: If you find a control which is a `Panel`, you need to also search the panel's children.

---

I edited my code according to the comments - just remembered the `Find` method, too.

Comment: The Control Collection has a Find Method that does (more or less) what the first code does. And it does it recursively.

Answer (score 6):

The code snippet you have shown yields that exception because of the line

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = objCheckBox as CheckBox;
```

The `as` operator tries to cast the left operand into the type specified in the right operand. If the cast fails, the result will be `null`.

In your case, `objCheckBox` is a `string`. `string` cannot be converted into `CheckBox`, hence the result that gets saved in `myCheckBox` is `null`.

---

Instead, use one of the following methods:

- Store all of your check boxes in an array. You will then be able to access the elements in that array directly with their index (which you seem to have stored in the `index` variable).
- Depending on which UI toolkit you are using, there should be a method to *find a control by its name*. Pass the complete check box name to that method, and it will return the appropriate `CheckBox` instance (if found).